# Deflate compress a string in mule

Tags: mule, mule4

I wanted to know if there's any way to compress a string using deflate algorithm in Mule 4. I am aware of Kryo serialization framework in mule, but I am not sure of the  correct configuration and how to verify the compressed string.Any code snippet of the same will be greatly useful.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Compression Module](https://docs.mulesoft.com/connectors/compression/compression-module) offers zip and gzip compression/decompression operations. Both formats use the deflate algorithm.

If you don't the gzip or zip formats and only want the deflate compression, then you probably need to implement it yourself in a [Java class](https://docs.mulesoft.com/connectors/java/java-module) or [create your own module](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-sdk/1.1/), and call from there a Java implementation of Deflate, like https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/zip/Deflater.html.

Comment: Thanks for the info @aled. The thing is, before I go into implementing the logic in a java class, I have to make sure that there's no out-of-the-box solution available in mule 4.Let me know if you get any other ideas or info.

Comment: Nothing other than what I have already mentioned. It should be a pretty straightforward implementation if you have to go that way. You could even use a Groovy script as an alternative to a Java class. I recommend creating a connector as a more long term solution.